# Android command-line executable: Segmentation fault

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, arm

I try to compile a do-nothing program and what I get is a segmentation fault.

*exe1.c:*

```
int main() {
    return 12;
}
```

*Android.mk:*

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := exe1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := exe1.c
#LOCAL_CFLAGS += -save-temps
#LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

And I get:

```
root@android:/ # exe1
[1] + Stopped (signal)     exe1 
root@android:/ # 
[1] + Segmentation fault   exe1 
root@android:/ #
```

(the console output evidently is a bit buggy, the 2nd line is not shown after the executed command.)

**How do I make it work? (I need at least the hello-word functionality.)**

UPDATE:

```
root@android:/ # strace exe1                                                   
execve("/system/bin/exe1", ["exe1"], [/* 22 vars */]) = 0
```

(UDPATE2: oops! it looks like this strace does not work at all!)

Comment: run it with strace if available also check kernel logs with 'cat /proc/kmsg'. Are you building with ndk?

Comment: @auselen yes, with NDK

Comment: `file exe1` or `arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -a exe1`

Comment: I mean make sure you are getting a sensible binary from build.

Comment: Reverted 3rd-party tag edit: there exist architecture-specific reasons for faults such as ARM's prohibition on unaligned access.